# Function with throws doesn't exit the function with executes trow

Tags: swift, error-handling

I have the following function with throws:

```
func doSomething(_ myArray: [Int]) throws -> Int {

    if myArray.count == 0 {
        throw arrayErrors.empty
    }
    return myArray[0]
}
```

But when the array is equal to 0 it will throw the error but it will continue executing the function returning empty array.

How can I exit the function when goes to the if statement ?

Comment: What do you mean by "returning empty array"? Your function returns an `Int`.

Comment: The statements you make in your question can't be true and most of them make little sense. When you say *"when the array is equal to 0"*, do you actually mean "when the array is empty"? And no, if the "throw" line is actually called, it will not continue on to the `return` line and nothing will be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand error handling. If you insert a `throws` keyword, anybody calling it will need to use a `do-catch` statement, `try?`, `try!` or continue to propagate them. So what will happen if the error is thrown is up to the caller.

Here's an example:

```
do {
  try doSomething(foo)
} catch arrayErrors.empty {
  fatalError("Array is empty!")
}
```

Apple's documentation for [error handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

If you want to exit once you reach the `if`, simply don't use error handling and call `fatalError` inside the if.

```
if myArray.count = 0 {
  fatalError("Error happened")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function does return when you throw an error. Pop this in a playground and look at the output.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

enum MyError: Error {
    case emptyArray
}

func doSomething<T>(_ array: [T]) throws -> T {
    guard !array.isEmpty else {
        throw MyError.emptyArray
    }

    return array[0]
}

do {
    let emptyArray: [Int] = []
    let x = try doSomething(emptyArray)
    print("x from emptyArray is \(x)")
} catch {
    print("error calling doSeomthing on emptyArray: \(error)")
}

do {
    let populatedArray = [1]
    let x = try doSomething(populatedArray)
    print("x from populatedArray is \(x)")
} catch {
    print("error calling doSeomthing on emptyArray: \(error)")
}
```

You'll see the output is

```
error calling doSeomthing on emptyArray: emptyArray
x from populatedArray is 1
```

Note that you don't see the output from `print("x from emptyArray is \(x)")` because it was never called, because `throw` ends the execution of that function. You can also confirm this because `guard` statements require the function to exit.

Also, just to note, if you want the first thing from an array you can just use `myArray.first` which will return `T?`, and you can handle the nil case instead of having to deal with an error. For example:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

let myArray = [1, 2, 3]

if let firstItem = myArray.first {
    print("the first item in myArray is \(firstItem)")
} else {
    print("myArray is empty")
}

let myEmptyArray: [Int] = []

if let firstItem = myEmptyArray.first {
    print("the first item in myEmptyArray is \(firstItem)")
} else {
    print("myEmptyArray is empty")
}
```

which outputs:

```
the first item in myArray is 1
myEmptyArray is empty
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first sentence be "The function *doesn't* return when you throw an error."?